# Sulu: Is it possible to limit the available page templates per webspace?

Tags: sulu

I have a sulu 1.6 installation with multiple webspaces. I have multiple page template definitions in `app/Resources/templates/pages`, like `default.xml`, `homepage.xml`, `blog.xml`, `center.xml`.

Is it possible to make for example the `center.xml` only available for the content of one webspace and not all the others?

**UPDATDE:**
Where can I change this behaviour in the code, that per webspace only the ones are showing up, that are defined in the webspace.xml? This is really blocking and a super bad user experience, since the template is directly linked together with the configured webspace, but the others do not fit.

Thx a lot!
Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template is only shown in the dropdown if its `.html.twig` file exists. So if you use the [SuluThemeBundle](https://github.com/sulu/suluthemebundle) and only a specific [theme](http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/book/themes.html) implements its `.html.twig` file the template will not be shown on the other theme aslong as the .html.twig does not exists there.

Comment: Mate, what an awesome workaround! Also: if only one page type should be available, it should not be called `default` but something more unique.

Answer (score 0):

This feature has not yet been implemented, because not too many people have asked for it...

Answer (score 0):

Since Sulu 2.0 you can limit the template on the webspace using the exclude-templates inside your webspace configuration:

```xml
<excluded-templates>
    <excluded-template>overview</excluded-template>
</excluded-templates>
```

Before the only way to limit page templates was to work with themes.