# Sulu CMS 2: Webspace specific templates are no longer hidden

Tags: sulu

in sulu 1.6 it was possible to limit the available page types per webspace via a [workaround by limiting the theme tenplate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028119/sulu-is-it-possible-to-limit-the-available-page-templates-per-webspace)

Now after the migration to 2.0 They are all showing up:

[image]

The workaround is still in place, by only providing the templates for certain themes:

[image]

Is there a different way to filter out Available Page Types in Sulu 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mechanism changed in Sulu 2.0. It was very confusing to newcomers, that their new template didn't show up in this list, when they forgot to add the twig template in the correct way (also there was no clue about what was wrong).

So we decided to make this behavior more explicit, and now there is [the `excluded-templates` tag](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.0/book/webspaces.html?highlight=exclude-templates#excluded-templates-optional), which allows you to do that in a very explicit way.